# Runtime Error 1004 when setting cell value to a variable of type double

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I'm having difficulties understanding why I keep getting this error. I have the following code:

```
Public Var as Double, Rng2 as Range
Option Explicit
Sub Example()
Dim R as Range, Rng as Range
Dim Row as Long
Set Rng = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
SetRanges 'This is a sub routine that scans Row 1 of my Spreadsheet and sets Rng2 to the
'appropriate column. IE I'm looking for Name Change column. As I'm still developing this
'sheet I expect I may end up moving this column at some point. I would like to avoid
'needing to come back into the macro to adjust if possible
For each R in Rng
  Row = R.Row
  If "Logic Statement" then
    Calc 'Calc is a sub in another module that calculates the value of Var which results in
         '0.72658 right now. The reason I pass the variable is because I'm referring to a
         'new workbook with a different set of ranges. 
  Else
    MsgBox "Error Statement"
    Exit Sub
  EndIf
  Rng2.Rows(Row).Value = Var 'This is the line giving me the Runtime Error
Next R
End Sub
```

I don't understand why this is giving me the RunTime Error 1004 "Application Defined or Object Defined error." I have other macros in the same sheet doing something similar. The only difference is instead of running a calculation I'm simply pulling data over by saying `Rng2.Rows(Row).Value = DataRng.Rows(DataRow).Value`. Am I declaring my Var as the wrong type or is it something else?

Comment: try: `Range("B" & Row).Value = Var`

Comment: What is the value of `var'? Btw your code cannot work as posted as can't have a Public statement inside a sub.

Comment: I'm not able to do that. I'm not sure which column Rng2 ends up being in as I have set it to Dynamic. I'm updating my code now. I apologize.

Comment: Ok, I have moved my Var outside of the subs above the `Option Explicit` in my macro. I still run into this error. The value based on the sheet I'm looking at is currently 0.72658 which is what I would expect it to be. That's why I declared Double.

Comment: Looks like the problem is with Rng2. `Rng2` is a local variable in this Sub and has not been set anywhere here. When you set Rng2 in another subroutine `SetRanges`, it will not set this variable unless you pass a reference to the local `Rng2` variable.

Comment: I agree with @PankajR.  If `Rng2` is set to some range within your macro, then it runs without error.  And you cannot declare a `Public` within the `Sub`.  You need to declare it before the `Sub` line

Comment: Ok, I have now updated my code. Thanks for the help. :) Now that my Rng2 is outside the Sub, it appears to at least set the variable correctly. However, my code is still breaking on the same line with the same error :(

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line.  When the sub stops, in the immediate window, type   `?Rng2.Rows(Row).address`  What do you get?

Comment: It changed the code to `Print Rng2.Rows(Row).Address` and now that line is giving me a compile error that says "Method not valid without suitable object."

Comment: I also tried running this line in the sub routine that sets this variable and it gives the same compile error "Method not valid without suitable object."

Comment: You should ask your question in such a way that it doesn't depend on subs whose code you don't include. Please read [mcve].

Comment: That confirms that the problem is with `Rng2`.  You are not setting it correctly.

Comment: Every one thank you for your time. I had to rewrite this code because of the sensitive data I work with when posting here. As Such I found my original code had the line `Row = R.Row` inside of the Calc sub routine. Since it was not a public variable it was causing the object error. By moving this line outside the if statement it is working as expected. However, your advice on the other sections is greatly appreciated and I'm sure it prevented any other errors that may have popped up. Also, this resolved the compile error for the line `?Rng2.Rows(Row).Address`.